# Get previous four weeks with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure to get data from the last four weeks:

```
Last four weeks = CALCULATE(SUM(THEFT[AMOUNT_STOLEN]);FILTER(THEFT;DATEDIFF(THEFT[DATE_STOLEN];TODAY();WEEK)<5))
```

I want a second measure that gets the previous 4 weeks so I can divide these two measures. I can't get that to work. I've tried something like this but it gives me no data:

```
Previous four weeks = CALCULATE(SUM(THEFT[AMOUNT_STOLEN]);FILTER(THEFT;DATEDIFF(THEFT[DATE_STOLEN];TODAY();WEEK)>4)) && CALCULATE(SUM(THEFT[AMOUNT_STOLEN]);FILTER(THEFT;DATEDIFF(THEFT[DATE_STOLEN];TODAY();WEEK)<9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the second criteria into your filter function:

```
Previous four weeks = CALCULATE(SUM(THEFT[AMOUNT_STOLEN]);FILTER(THEFT;DATEDIFF(THEFT[DATE_STOLEN];TODAY();WEEK)>4 && DATEDIFF(THEFT[DATE_STOLEN];TODAY();WEEK)<9))
```